# Display values of datetime to different rows in a DataGridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Here's my table.

```
attendance
empID          int(11)
time_stamp     datetime
in_out         char(3)      *determines in / out of employee
am_pm          char(2)      *determines if morning/afternoon shift
```

The image below shows the output that I am trying to come up with. I need to display the values of time_stamp of datetime datatype into a DataGrid in vb.net.

I know how to use date_format. I just don't know how to SELECT the data to have them displayed that way.

DATABASE INPUT

```
empID  |  time_stamp          |   in_out  |   am_pm
  152  | 2016-01-01 12:00:00  |   out     |   am
  152  | 2016-01-01 08:00:00  |   in      |   am
  152  | 2016-01-02 12:00:00  |   out     |   am
  152  | 2016-01-02 08:00:00  |   in      |   am
  152  | 2016-01-03 12:00:00  |   out     |   am
  152  | 2016-01-03 08:00:00  |   in      |   am
  152  | 2016-01-01 05:00:00  |   out     |   pm
  152  | 2016-01-01 01:00:00  |   in      |   pm
  152  | 2016-01-02 05:00:00  |   out     |   pm
  152  | 2016-01-02 01:00:00  |   in      |   pm
  152  | 2016-01-03 05:00:00  |   out     |   pm
  152  | 2016-01-03 01:00:00  |   in      |   pm
```

DESIRED OUTPUT for employee 152

```
DAY  |        AM           |        PM           |
1    | 8:00:00   12:00:00  |  1:00:00   5:00:00  |
2    | 8:00:00   12:00:00  |  1:00:00   5:00:00  |
3    | 8:00:00   12:00:00  |  1:00:00   5:00:00  |
```

[image: hard copy of the daily time record]

Comment: I recommend you make a temporary DataTable in memory and use a loop to populate it from the results of your SELECT query. While it is possible to transpose data etc. in SQL, I suspect you will find it much easier to transform the data within VB code

Comment: In addition, you might want to consider using multiple `DataGridView`s for the UI display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT empID, emp_day, MAX(am_in1) as am_in, MAX(am_out1) as am_out, MAX(pm_in1) as pm_in, MAX(pm_out1) as pm_out
FROM (
SELECT empID, DATE_FORMAT(`time_stamp`,'%e') as emp_day,
CASE WHEN am_pm='am' AND in_out='in' THEN DATE_FORMAT(`time_stamp`,'%T') ELSE '' END as am_in1,
CASE WHEN am_pm='am' AND in_out='out' THEN DATE_FORMAT(`time_stamp`,'%T') ELSE '' END as am_out1,
CASE WHEN am_pm='pm' AND in_out='in' THEN DATE_FORMAT(`time_stamp`,'%T') ELSE '' END as pm_in1,
CASE WHEN am_pm='pm' AND in_out='out' THEN DATE_FORMAT(`time_stamp`,'%T') ELSE '' END as pm_out1
FROM attendance
) as o
GROUP BY empID, emp_day
```

The subquery formats the desired columns and the main query groups to get one row per employee per day.

EDIT: [here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/139ca0/1/0)

Comment: Thank you so much @moni_dragu. That is exactly what I was trying to do! 

Comment: i was wondering if it's possible to keep the dates for the whole month even if there is no record yet for logins and outs? Like for January, the **Day** column must be filled with 1 to 31. Should I make another table for DATE maybe? Thank you so much again.

Comment: You have more options to do this. You can, as you said, build a separate table for the dates and join it with the above sub query. Or you could handle the missing days in your vb.net code.

Comment: moni_dragu, maybe you can help me as well with another problem, i tried using your query with a date query.. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161491/join-another-query-to-display-all-days-of-the-month-with-or-without-values